# SQL Server error when importing excel report

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to import an excel file using the following code

```
select * 
from  OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                  'Excel 16.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Users\Public\Documents\budget.xlsx', 
                  'select * from [budget$]')
```

but I keep getting the following error message:

> Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.

I am using Excel version 16 64 bit, SQL Server 2017 64-bit on a Windows Server 64 bit.

Also i have installed  Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and version 2016 as well for no avail.

Appreciate if someone can assist me on this.

Warm Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe – Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable.

This download will install a set of components that facilitate the transfer of data between existing Microsoft Office files such as Microsoft Office Access 2010 (*.mdb and *.accdb) files and Microsoft Office Excel 2010 (*.xls, *.xlsx, and *.xlsb) files to other data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server.

So thus installing Microsoft Office Data Connectivity Components – AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe fixed the issue.

From https://moredvikas.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/the-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-has-not-been-registered-error-with-excel-file-linked-server-accessdatabaseengine_x64-exe/

To download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Hi Rim96, I have already tried that, all versions from 32 bit to 64 bit and it doesn't show in the providers list

Comment: giving a little bump

Comment: giving another bump

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with "it doesn't show in the providers list"? It's only two .exe according to you OS